# Data Defined Override for Hex Colour - QGIS 3.4.1

Tags: qgis

Under `Properties > Labels > Background` there is an inconsistency between the tooltip and how string colours are interpreted. See here:
[image]

Comment: **Please make software bug reports directly to the software provider.**  https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues/

Answer (score 1):

When using hex the format is interpreted as #AARRGGBB.

This appears to be a bug since RGB is interpreted [r,g,b] and [r,g,b,a] (consistent) while hex is interpretet [#rrggbb] or [#aarrggbb] (inconsistent).

Comment: Right - it was a bug in the helper text used here. It's been fixed in 3.4.3